# Possible to index store with Core Data when using the NSInMemoryStoreType?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, core-data

I have an NSArray of a few thousand in-memory NSDictionary instances (containing strings and numbers) against which I need to perform arbitrary queries at runtime. Using filteredArrayUsingPredicate winds up yielding unacceptable performance. I could manually build up indices on each field and access those dictionaries, but I figured it might be simpler to just build up a dynamic in-memory Core Data model with indexed attributes, convert the NSDictionary instances into NSManagedObjects, and then perform the queries with NSFetchRequests.

Unfortunately, the NSInMemoryStoreType model doesn't seem to respect the "indexed" property of the NSAttributeDescription: queries against the Core Data model are taking about 50% longer than just doing the old filteredArrayUsingPredicate on the array of dictionaries. Is there some trick to getting a NSInMemoryStoreType model to create in-memory indices, or does is the attribute simply ignored? Using a SQLite store is not an option for this application, since the types of the attributes change frequently.

Here's the code I'm using to compare the performance of the two different searching mechanisms:

```
- (void)testInMemoryCoreDataEfficienctQuery {
    static const NSInteger InstanceCount = 5000; // the number of instances to test

    static NSString *EntityName = @"EntityPerformanceTest";
    static NSString *AttributeName = @"attrName";
    static NSString *PredicateVariable = @"predicateVariable";

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc;
    NSEntityDescription *entity;
    {
        NSManagedObjectModel *mom = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] init];
        {
            NSMutableArray *entities = [NSMutableArray array];
            entity = [[NSEntityDescription alloc] init];
            entity.name = EntityName;

            NSMutableArray *attrs = [NSMutableArray array];
            {
                NSAttributeDescription *attr = [[NSAttributeDescription alloc] init];
                attr.name = AttributeName;
                attr.attributeType = NSStringAttributeType;
                attr.indexed = YES; // ideally this would speed up searches on strings
                [attrs addObject:attr];
            }

            entity.properties = attrs;

            [entities addObject:entity];

            mom.entities = entities;
        }
        NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:mom];

        NSPersistentStore *ps = [psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSInMemoryStoreType configuration:nil URL:nil options:nil error:&error];
        // NSPersistentStore *ps = [psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString randomUUID]] stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"sqlite"]] options:nil error:&error];

        STAssertNotNil(ps, nil);
        STAssertNil(error, @"%@", error);

        moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
        moc.persistentStoreCoordinator = psc;
    }
    [moc processPendingChanges];
    [moc save:&error];
    [moc reset];
    STAssertNil(error, @"%@", error);

    // now test searching in a MOC vs. in a collection of dictionaries
    NSMutableArray *strings = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray *dicts = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:InstanceCount];
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < InstanceCount; i++) {
            // create an arbitrary random string we will store and later query against
            CFUUIDRef randomUUID = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
            NSString *uuidString = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, randomUUID));
            CFRelease(randomUUID);

            [strings addObject:uuidString];

            // create the dictionary
            NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
            [dict setValue:uuidString forKey:AttributeName];
            [dicts addObject:dict];

            // create the managed instance
            NSManagedObject *ob = [[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:moc];
            [ob setValue:uuidString forKey:AttributeName];
        }
    }
    [moc processPendingChanges];

    STAssertEquals([strings count], [[NSSet setWithArray:strings] count], @"strings were not unique");

    NSPredicate *query = [NSComparisonPredicate predicateWithLeftExpression:[NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:AttributeName] rightExpression:[NSExpression expressionForVariable:PredicateVariable] modifier:(NSDirectPredicateModifier) type:(NSEqualToPredicateOperatorType) options:(0)];

    for (int iter = 0; iter < 2; iter++) {
        NSFetchRequest *fetch = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:EntityName];
        [fetch setFetchLimit:1];
        [fetch setFetchBatchSize:1];

        // time searching with Core Data
        CFAbsoluteTime mocStart = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
        for (int i = 0; i < InstanceCount; i++) {
            fetch.predicate = [query predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[strings objectAtIndex:arc4random() % strings.count] forKey:PredicateVariable]];

            NSArray *results = [moc executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];
            NSParameterAssert(!error);
            NSParameterAssert(results.count == 1);
        }
        CFAbsoluteTime mocEnd = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();

        // time searching with dictionaries
        CFAbsoluteTime dictStart = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
        for (int i = 0; i < InstanceCount; i++) {
            NSArray *results = [dicts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[query predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[strings objectAtIndex:arc4random() % strings.count] forKey:PredicateVariable]]];
            NSParameterAssert(results.count == 1);
        }
        CFAbsoluteTime dictEnd = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();

        NSLog(@"assessed %d queries: moc=%.3f dict=%.3f", InstanceCount, mocEnd - mocStart, dictEnd - dictStart);

        /*
         Core Data seems to be slower, as per these results:

         2012-01-10 21:19:04.247 Glimpse[9151:15503] assessed 5000 queries: moc=19.085 dict=12.186
         2012-01-10 21:19:35.412 Glimpse[9151:15503] assessed 5000 queries: moc=19.001 dict=12.164
         */
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use a sqlite store that's just a temporary file? Delete the file when your app closes and put it in the temp directory so that if your app dies or something, the system can clean it up if it needs to.

Comment: Because the data is generated and re-generated frequently (e.g., whenever the user taps a button). The cost of writing the data to the flash memory would far outweigh any benefits gained from using a sqlite index.

Comment: I think the ideal solution then would be to use SQLite with an in-memory database? SQLite supports that — see e.g. http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html — but I can't seem to formulate an `NSURL` version that passes the SQL persistent store's URL validation.